# Can I open a php file from another device on the same wifi as my rpi3?

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi3

My raspberry pi 3 has apache2 installed and i have run a php file in it smoothly. Can I open this php file from my android phone browser if it is connected to the same wifi as my pi? I am very new to php and this is for a school project.

Comment: There's "opening a file for reading" and then there's "executing a file a reading the output". Both are very different things. Web servers like Apache _execute_ a file and show you the output, not the code, via the browser. Your phone can connect to the Raspberry Pi and view this output, if that is what you are asking, you just need to know the Raspberry Pi's IP address (and maybe have the firewall setup and process listening on that IP). Your phone probably cannot _execute_ the PHP file without some third-party package which I don't even know if it exists.

Comment: I want to execute the file. I know the raspberry pi 3 address too by typing ifconfig wlan0. How should I connect my phone to the raspberry pi to view the output?

Comment: Open your browser on your phone and enter that IP along with potentially a port, path and querystring, just like a normal web site. It is possible that your network doesn't allow inter-device communications. It is also possible that your raspberry pi doesn't allow outside communication. You might need to troubleshoot both and unfortunately fixing those problems are outside the scope of this website.

Comment: Yeah this solved my issue, there was some firewalls that was causing the issue